# I am getting error in matplotlib when I am imporing it in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Dear Experts,
when I am writing in jn `%matplotlib inline` I am getting following error. Could you please suggest me a solution for this.

*Error*

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

Comment: are you sure you have got matplotlib installed

Comment: how to check that ?

Comment: use pip list and then search for matplotlib and then use conda list and do the same

Comment: after doing conda list I found matplotlib with version 3.2.2. But in build channel there is zero in that column. Don't know why ?

Comment: Hello ! What should I do now ?

Comment: Sorry But I dont think I could help.

Comment: Anyone please ?